# Merging text rows into an array in psql when another row values match

Tags: sql, postgresql

My current table looks like this:

```
id | col1 | col2
1  |  a   |  z
2  |  b   |  y
3  |  a   |  w
4  |  c   |  x
5  |  b   |  z
```

I would like to combine the values in col2 into an array based on the repeated values in col1, making my col1 UNIQUE. My expected output is this:

```
id | col1 | col2
1  |  a   |  {z, w }
2  |  b   |  {y, z }
4  |  c   |  { x }
```

I am unsure how to do this in postgres. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_agg()`:

```
select min(id), col1, array_agg(col2)
from t
group by col1;
```